# Firefox keeps deleting Cache after exit

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-cache

I've been trying to retain the Firefox cache for a while now, but for some reason, it keeps getting cleared when I exit Firefox. I need the cache to improve the performance of a website as it loads a large Batch.js file, which takes about 30 seconds.

In the Firefox about:config settings, the following is set:

-browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled false

-browser.cache.disk.capacity 1048576

I have also unchecked "Clear cookies and site data when Firefox is closed".

I'm really at a loss and would appreciate any help.
[This is how the cache2 folder looks like after closing Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYkgn.png)

Thank you in advance for your assistance